# How can I add buttons to the Windows title bar using C# and .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a Microsoft form app I'm working on, and I've been trying to add buttons ON the title bar, as well as keeping the default close/minimize buttons. Something like the image below explains visually what I'm targeting for.

[image]

If anyone could take the time to help me out here id appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Please have look here: http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-menu.htm

Comment: What do you call the "title bar"? What is it on the image you posted that shows what you want?

Comment: That's the menu bar. There's controls specifically for the menu that you can add to your projects. If you wanted the window around the title bar to have buttons on it, then that would need to be a part of the window itself, not the title bar of the window. Treat that portion of the window similarly to the title bar, but because it's part of the form it could have controls on it. That's a lot more effort than adding a menu control though

Comment: So i know how MenuStrips work, and that's defiantly what I want here! Though, im only able to place that anywhere in the red box, left side of the [image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/images/clientarea-sidebyside.png). While I want it to be "placeable" anywhere in the red square of the right side of the image.

Comment: there is no red box anywhere

Comment: Did you look at this image here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/images/clientarea-sidebyside.png

Comment: Ah, yes. Im using WinForms

Comment: If you talk about the border then consider the border not really part of your application(its non-client area). Its shown and maintained by windows. You can choose from the set of standard behaviors but doing something completely else gets complex. One way is removing borders and doing everything yourself or handling the Windows messages directly to get windows to add a button there and interact with the button (lookup WM_NCPAINT messages).

Comment: While the image shows a menu bar (in particular the one of Visual Studio) it's got rather common to have that _on_ the title bar. VS as well as various browsers meanwhile have the menu on the title bar. Saves a bit of screen estate.

Comment: If you want to add a Menu bar to the *Title bar* (Window Caption), you need to move it into the Client Area, using `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea()`; see [Custom Window Frame Using DWM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dwm/customframe) -- In Windows 11, you can make use of the Windows App SDK's [AppWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.windowing.appwindow) (it's framework-agnostic, it can be used in WinForms) to - partially - handle Title Bar features